# Z - Axis value is changing if I move the Game Object in X - Axis in Unity

Tags: c#, movement, unity, axis

I am on a small game project . Everything was just fine , but now I have some wired problem . That is Game Object movement . If I move the game object in X - Axis using the gizmo , the value of Z - Axis is changing . And if move in Z - Axis the value of X - Axis is changing . This is totally wired to me .

The game object is Empty Game Object and It is in the scene as a Child . Its position is as follow :-

```
One Game Object
      Another Game Object
           My Empty Game Object which is acting wired
```

Here are the screen shots :-

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

So why it is behaving so wired ? What is the problem ?

I hope you will help me to figure it out .

Regards

NB :)

Comment: Parent rotated? You seem to be using Global positioning, it won't mirror the parent rotations.

Comment: Oh Man , Thanks , You saved My Night (Now it's night in India) . Big Hug :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the two parents is rotated 90 degrees around the Y axis.  I can't be sure which way, but you can "fix" this by toggling Global/Local gizmos (its one of the two buttons in the upper-left corner, just above the "scene" tab).

That, or un-rotating the parent object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , I rotated 'Another Game Object' 90 degrees . Helped a lot :)